# Android: ListView headers lost when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

So I have the following view

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSessionItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblGroupDate"
        style="@style/CustomText.GrayTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblCourseCode"
            style="@style/CustomText.GrayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblSessionCode"
            style="@style/CustomText.GrayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So basically I get the following data from the database:

COURSE_CODE

SESSION_CODE

SESSION_DATE

I need to group the ListView items by SESSION_DATE, what I do is I keep a variable called "PreviousDate" and I compare it to the current SESSION_DATE, if it's different then I enable the header with the ID: "lblGroupDate" if the dates are the same I Hide "lblGroupDate".

Here's my Adapter:

```
public class SessionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Date PreviousDate = new Date();

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView lblGroupDate;
        TextView lblCourseCode;
        TextView lblSessionCode;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.lblGroupDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGroupDate);
            holder.lblCourseCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCourseCode);
            holder.lblSessionCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSessionCode);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }   

        SessionData session = (SessionData) getItem(position);

        if(session != null) {

            Date sessionDate = session.SESSION_DATE;

            if (!mPrevDate.equals(sessionDate)) {

                PreviousDate = sessionDate;

                // HIDE GROUP HEADER
                holder.lblGroupDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                // SHOW GROUP HEADER
                holder.lblGroupDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            holder.lblCourseCode.setText(session.COURSE_CODE);
            holder.lblSessionCode.setText(session.SESSION_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the **PROBLEM**:

Lets say I have 20 records, when I scroll down and then scroll up again the rows that had the Group Header (lblGroupDate) enabled get shifted up without a header, it's the header was shifted to the next 3 rows. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would recommend using (and extending) the [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html) which has the capability to group items.

Comment: I think you also missing "convertView.setTag(holder)" in if condition at "getView" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because getView() can be called at anytime and out-of-order from your data-set. You need to create a data-set that the adapter can be backed by. Just sorting your adapter out. Will update answer with code in a moment.

**SessionListAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SessionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private static final int TYPE_GROUP   = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SESSION = 1;
    private static final int MAX_TYPES    = 2;

    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<SessionViewData> mData;


    public SessionListAdapter(Context context, List<SessionData> sessionData)
    {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        updateSessionViewData(sessionData);
    }

    public void updateSessionViewData(List<SessionData> sessionData)
    {
        Date previousDate = new Date();
        ArrayList<SessionViewData> data = new ArrayList<SessionViewData>();
        for(SessionData session: sessionData){
            if(!previousDate.equals(session.SESSION_DATE)){
                data.add(new SessionViewData(TYPE_GROUP, session));
                previousDate = session.SESSION_DATE;
            }
            data.add(new SessionViewData(TYPE_SESSION, session));
        }
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        SessionViewData data = mData.get(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            final int layoutId;
            switch(data.type){
                case TYPE_GROUP:   layoutId = R.layout.list_session_group; break;
                case TYPE_SESSION: layoutId = R.layout.list_session_item;  break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad type for: " + data.session);
            }
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        }

        switch(data.type){
            case TYPE_GROUP:
                TextView lblGroupDate = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGroupDate));
                lblGroupDate.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(convertView.getContext(), 
                    data.session.SESSION_DATE.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE));
                break;

            case TYPE_SESSION:
                TextView lblCourseCode  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCourseCode);
                lblCourseCode.setText(data.session.COURSE_CODE);
                TextView lblSessionCode = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSessionCode);
                lblSessionCode.setText(data.session.SESSION_CODE);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position).type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return MAX_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mData.size();
    }


    static class SessionViewData
    {
        int         type;
        SessionData session;


        public SessionViewData(int type, SessionData session)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.session = session;
        }
    }
}
```

**list_session_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lblGroupDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomText.GrayTitle"
    />
```

**list_session_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSessionItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCourseCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CustomText.GrayText"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSessionCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CustomText.GrayText"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you could provide a code example that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer with code example. Not run it.. but it should work. Let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution but it's not working for some reason, I'll update question and let you know... Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of how I can use this? Lets say I want to populate this from a database, I need to create an Async task, call the web service and populate this, and then use it in my List Fragment, can you give me an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: Just create your ListView and set the adapter like `list.setAdapter(new SessionListAdapter(getActivity(), yourData))`

Comment: Lets say I have a ListFragment that overrides this method: public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View itemView, int position, long id) How do I get the mData array from this function in order to get the selected item? I can get the selected item through SessionViewData viewData = (SessionViewData) list.getAdapter().getItem(position); but since getItem gets the item from the list view it's not the same as the itmes from the array.